# webEngine load another page

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I'm having trouble understanding how to load another page into the webEngine after I've already made a webEngine.load call.
I've noticed that after initializing the web view of the browser the execution of the program waits the windows to close, since I need to make checks every 20 seconds I've made another thread that initialize the web view.

```
public class MainBrowser extends Application {
    private Scene scene;
    private static String json;
    private static Browser browser;

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // create the scene
        stage.setTitle("Web View");

        Rectangle2D screenSize = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        double width = screenSize.getWidth();
        double height = screenSize.getHeight();

        //System.out.println("Defining a new scene...");
        browser = new Browser(json);
        scene = new Scene(browser,width,height, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        //scene.getStylesheets().add("webviewsample/BrowserToolbar.css");
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String j){
        json = j;
        launch();
    }

    public static void reload(String j){
        json = j;
        browser.reloadPage(j);
    }
}
```

This is what I've used to call the browser

```
private static void openBrowserWindow(String json)
{
    browserRunnable = new BrowserRunnable(json);
    browserThread = new Thread(browserRunnable);
    browserThread.start();

}

private static void reloadBrowserWindow(String json)
{
    browserRunnable.reloadBrowser(json);        
}
```

And with this function I try to call the browser in another thread and then to load another page. Naturally it doesn't work, but I really don't know how to make the webEngine loading another page:

```
public class BrowserRunnable implements Runnable {
    static MainBrowser browser;
    static String json;

    public void reloadBrowser(String json)
    {
        this.json = json;
        MainBrowser.reload(json);
    }

    public BrowserRunnable(String json)
    {
        this.json = json;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        MainBrowser.main(json);
    }
}
```

reloading function in browser:

```
public void reloadPage(String json)
{
    File openpage = new File(Config.PAGE_LOCAL_URL);
    String param = "?json=" + json;
    System.out.println(param);
    webEngine.load(openpage.toURI().toString() + param);
}
```

I know there is a lot of code, but it's just for showing the overall, I just need to know how to update the page of my webEngine

Comment: Can't you just call the `load()` method a second time with a different URL?

Comment: it's what I'm trying to do, but the call of the method is executed only after I close the webview (that I need open)